# C++ perform type checking but do not compile file

Tags: c++

Is there a way to type check a C++ translation unit without compiling it, using either a compiler driver like clang or gcc or an external tool. There are a lot of static analysis tools out there ... I'm wondering about detecting type errors specifically, not (for instance) detecting questionable usage or undefined behavior.

The closest thing I've been able to find is something like this, which just generates assembly and writes it to `/dev/null`, hopefully avoiding some expensive code paths in the compiler itself.

```
% clang++ -o- -S foo.cc > /dev/null
```

I'm wondering if there are any alternatives and what the pros/cons are.

Comment: Type errors typically only show up during compilation. So basically you want to compile a file without generating the corresponding object file/executable?

Comment: If it passes the check, will you then compile it?

Comment: @cup ... yes, but that's only part of what I'm using this for. I was also hoping to study the tool ... and learn more about the typing rules for C++.

It's a shame that the old answer was deleted. the `-emit-llvm` option is a pretty good one for just detecting type errors as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

g++ compiler flag: -fsyntax-only
or [Flycheck](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck)

Comment: List of tools for static code analysis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C.2C_C.2B.2B

Comment: Those tools are more general than what I'm asking for ... which is just reporting type errors for a complete translation unit.